# Form with JSON and PHP. Filter according to the value of select

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

Im having a problem with a form that I need to get the data of a JSON with PHP (because it is an api and I must hide the request url).

I have 3 selects:

```
        <select name="state" id="state">
            <option value="" select>STATE</option>
        </select>

        <select name="city" id="city">
            <option value="" select>CITY</option>
        </select>

        <select name="company" id="company">
            <option value="" select>COMPANY</option>
        </select>
```

Json has the companies with their respective data:

```
"companies": [
{
    "company": "name x",
    "city": "sao paulo",
    "state": "SP"
}, 
{
    "company": "name y",
    "city": "belo horizonte",
    "state": "MG"
}, 
{
    "company": "name z",
    "city": "sao paulo",
    "state": "SP"
} ]
```

What I need:

1 - select #state: Display all states (without repetition).

2 - select #city: Display all cities according to the selected state above.

3 - select #company: Display all companies according to the city selected above.

How should I do?
I think I should use ajax requesting the php file with json embedded in it, but I dont know how to do it.

Important: I cant change the structure of JSON because it is an api that I dont have access to modifications.

Any good souls to help me with this?

Thank you.

Comment: Please, translate your question on English

Comment: Or just ask the same here: https://pt.stackoverflow.com. But for the sake of learning, you should try in English.

Comment: sorry, I didnt notice that I wasnt in portuguese section.. I already translate the post.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started:

```
<html>
  <body>
     <select name="state" id="state">
       <?php
         $json = file_get_contents('test.js');
         $data = json_decode($json, true);
           foreach($data['companies'] as $entry) {
             echo "<option value=".$entry['company']."select>".$entry['company']."</option>";
           }
        ?>
     </select>
   </body>
</html>
```

The code above will take in the json input, decode it into an array and then we can loop through the elements inside.

The variable $json takes external input, but you can amend this to fit your needs. If you want to test the code above, create a file called 'test.js' in the same directory.

There also seemed to be an issue with the json you provided, you were missing a few braces. This is correct:

```
{
        "companies": [{
                "company": "name x",
                "city": "sao paulo",
                "state": "SP"
            },
            {
                "company": "name y",
                "city": "belo horizonte",
                "state": "MG"
            },
            {
                "company": "name z",
                "city": "sao paulo",
                "state": "SP"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make ajax call and populate data based on selection, this may be helpful:

```
var resp_data;
$.ajax({
  url:"your_php_page_url.php", //it can be even third party api url like google
  success:function(e){
     //you will get your json data here
      resp_data = e;
     //Now iterate through your data to fill state dropdown
     var state = e.companies;
     var d = [];
    $.each(b, function(a,c){
     if(($.inArray(c.state,d)) == -1){
       $('#state').append('<option value="'+c.state+'">'+c.state+'</option>')
       d.push(c.state);
     }

   });
  }, //hope you are not posting any data, so I am skipping that part

});
```

This ends your state population. Now on basis of state dropdown change you will have to populate data. No need to make another ajax call if your response is same just save the response in a variable and reuse it. For city you can do it like this:

```
$('#state').on('change',function(){
    var state = $('#state option:selected').val(); //gives you value of state selected.
    var op_data = resp_data.companies;
    var d = [];
    $.each(op_data, function(a,c){
     if(($.inArray(c.city,d)) == -1 && c.state == state){
       $('#city').append('<option value="'+c.city+'">'+c.city+'</option>')
       d.push(c.city);
     }

   });
});
```

same goes for your company. You may give it a try for company yourself just like that!!! Please do tell me if you are stuck in something.

This code can be optimized more. It's just that I thought I should write in a detailed manner.

Cheers!!!